# Referential integrity

Tags: database, database-design

I have the following structure,

```
USERS (id_user (PK));

USERS_PROJECTS (id_user (FK), id_project (FK));

PROJECTS (id_project (PK), id_owner);
```

This structure keeps the integrity in the way that when user doesn't exist he cannot be associated to a new project, but what about `id_owner`?
This attribute should also be referencing table users and `id_user`.
So, very project can have many users associated with it, but one of them is the owner of the project. 
I would like to have referential integrity defined so that when project is created and id_owner entered, the user alredy exists in users table. 
How would you do it?

How about adding `id_owner` as a FK referencing table users?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've answered you own question.

Comment: I got confused with this cyclic references... USERS is connected to PROJECTS ower weak entity and then directly... I got confused :) Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you will need to add id_owner as a FK referencing table users, exactly as you say.